# What is $C^1$ in differential equations?

Tags: real-analysis, ordinary-differential-equations

I often see a $C^1$ associated with defining the Lipschitz condition of a vector-valued function $f \in C^1( \mathbb{E})$, but I don't know the name of whatever this object is or what it means. As far as I can tell, it has something to do with being able to differentiate a function $f$ once, or $k$ times in the $C^k$ case over the open subset $\mathbb{E}$.

Comment: You are right plus the derivative should be continuous in this open set.

Comment: $C^{k}$ is the set of functions that have continuous derivatives up to order $k$.

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Smoothness#Differentiability_classes

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If $k \in \mathbb N$, then $C^k(\mathbb{E})$ is the class of functions which are $k$-times differentiable and all derivatives of order $ \le k$ are continuous.

Comment: Okay, thank you.

Comment: It’s enough to say that the derivative of order $k$ is continuous

Answer (score 1):

You’re right. A  $C^{\infty}$ function is a smooth function, i.e. it has derivatives of all orders everywhere. $C^1$ functions are also called continuously differentiable functions (differential even everywhere and the derivative is continuous), and this can be generalised similarly for some natural number $k$.

Comment: This is not very standard notation

Comment: Oh shoot I put those in subscript, I’ll correct it thanks.

Comment: I was more referring to your using $\mathbb C$ rather than $C$ or $\mathcal C$ or $\mathscr C$

Comment: Oh crap. I have no clue why I did that.